# Probability of getting two $z$-scores that are within one standard deviation of each other

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, z-score

Randomly choose two $z$-scores following a normal distribution with mean 0 and standard deviation 1.* What is the probability that the $z$-scores are within one standard deviation of each other?

Comment: *I'm not sure if I stated this rigorously. In layman's terms, we will throw two darts at a standard normal distribution and assume that the darts will always land inside the distribution. The two $z$-scores that we will choose are the projections of these darts on the $x$-axis. For instance, choosing $z=0$ has the highest probability; choosing $z=-1$ and $z=1$ have the same probability; and choosing $z=1$ is more likely than choosing $z=2$.

Comment: The difference in Z scores has a Normal distribution with mean $0-0$ and variance $1^2 + (-1)^2.$  Can you finish it from there?

Comment: This problem was inspired by the song _Breakeven_ by The Script. Imagine that every heartbroken person assigns a value for the pain he or she is feeling after a breakup, where 0 is for "average" pain, and a $z$ farther from 0 gets chosen by fewer heartbroken persons. A couple can say that their hearts "broke even" if their "numerical" pains are within one standard deviation of each other. My guess is that this probability is small, that's why we almost always observe that "when a heart breaks no it don't break even".

Comment: Assuming what you said is true, then the probability we are looking for is 
$$P(-1/\sqrt{2}<z<1/\sqrt{2}) \approx 0.5205,$$
is that correct? But why is your statement true?

Comment: Depends on what 'within one SD' means. Which SD are you using? SD 1 for standard normal or SD $\sqrt{2}$ for difference?

Comment: @BruceET, SD $=1$.